# Document based app: which is the key window?

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode6

The code for the app is here (the Raiseman folder contains the files for the project):

https://github.com/bignerdranch/cocoa-programming-for-osx-5e/tree/master/Chapter%2011%20-%20Undo/RaiseMan

Each Document(window?) contains an NSTableView and two buttons:

[image]

The app uses an ArrayController to manage an array of Employees in the Document class, and the buttons add or remove Employees from the array.

I notice that if I click the Add Employee button and start editing the Employee's name in the NSTableView, and then before hitting Return to end editing, if I click on File>New to create a second Document, then click on Add Employee in the second Document, then edit the Employee's name and hit Return, the Return key is sent to the first Document, which ends the editing of the Employee's name in the first Document, while nothing changes in the second Document.  Why is that? I expected the window that contains the button I clicked on to be the key window, and therefore the Return key would be sent to the second window.

If I hit Return again, then editing ends in the second Document.

Comment: Do you start the editing in the first window with your own code?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, Yes.  The Add Employee button is connected to the `addEmployee(_:)` action in the Document class, and inside the action is the method call `tableView.editColumn(_:, row:, withEvent:, select:)`, where `tableView` is an outlet to the NSTableView.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. The NSTableRowData object is observing NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification for all objects, including the views in other windows.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause both NSTableViews to end editing when I hit Return?